# take input parameter as option, var=${1:-""}

Tags: bash

I see a script:

`var=${1:-""}`

The purpose is $1 is an option, but I don't understand what does it mean when using `-""` ?

What's the function of `-""`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is documented in the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Basically, you are looking at a sort of conditional assignment. In case `$1` is not initialized, the value of `""` is assigned, i.e. the empty string. If `$1` is initialized, it will be left alone.